# Is always a Crepant birational map between smooth varieties a small modification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Lemma: A crepant birational map between quasi-projective normal varieties with only terminal singularities is in fact small modifitacions, i.e. isomorphism in codimension 1.

So, if $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$ is a crepant birational map of smooth varieties and $p\in X$ a point, then $f|_{X-\{p\}} : X-\{ p\} \dashrightarrow Y-\{ f(p)\}$ is a crepant birational map between quasi-projective smooth varieties so is a small modification by the lemma above and then $f$ is a small modification.

Is it right or im missing something?

Comment: I don't see why you're removing a point.  As stated, the Lemma applies even before you remove the point.

Comment: I didnt notice that. So i think that the question is solved.